# error while doing JSON Serialization ErrorDomain Code=3840

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to delete a post in a table view, but I get an error while doing JSON serialization, in this line

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]
```

if i access the url through the browser, the data is successfully deleted in the database, and if it is accessed from the browser, it also gives the json response back like this

> {"message":"successfully deleted","result":1,"status":"Image has been
>   deleted from drive"}

but i got an error that says the json text did not start with array or object (code =3840), but as you can see above, it is a json dictionary

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

[image]

here is the full code i use. what went wrong in here? Thanks

```
func deletePost(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let tweet = tweetsArray[indexPath.row]
    let uuid = tweet["uuid"] as! String
    let imagePath = tweet["imagePath"] as! String

    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/Twitter/post.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let body = "uuid=\(uuid)&path=\(imagePath)"
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil {

            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]

                guard let parsedJSON = json else {
                    print("error while parsing JSON")
                    return
                }

                let jsonMessage = parsedJSON["message"]
                if jsonMessage != nil {
                    // hilangkan data di array
                    self.tweetsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    self.imagesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

                    // hilangkan rownya pada table view
                    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            catch {

                // get main queue to communicate back to user
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    let message = "\(error)"
                    self.showAlert(alertTitle: "sorry", alertMessage: message, actionTitle: "OK")
                })
                return
            }
        }
        else {

            // get main queue to communicate back to user
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                let message = "\(error!.localizedDescription)"
                self.showAlert(alertTitle: "sorry", alertMessage: message, actionTitle: "OK")
            })
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to Print out your server response. Please change the code in your catch block like. and identifying an error in server side or not.

Your server data is proper json formate then print out your server data and check a  server data is valid or not.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if let jsonData = data {
            do {
                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String: AnyObject]
                if let area = parsedData["AREA"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for a in area {
                        print(a["area_name"])
                        print(a["price"])
                    }
                }
            }
            catch let err{
                print("\n\n===========Error===========")
                print("Error Code: \(error!._code)")
                print("Error Messsage: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                if let data = data, let str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8){
                    print("Server Error: " + str)
                }
                debugPrint(error)
                print("===========================\n\n")

                debugPrint(err)
            }
        }
        else {
            debugPrint(error as Any)
        }

    }.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks ashvin, I have changed the code block in the catch section, i have found the problem now :)